# Why does substr not return undef at the end of a string?

Tags: perl, substr

I'm not sure whether this is defined behaviour or not. I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = 'aaaaaa0aaaa';
my $char = substr($string, length($string), 1);
my $char2 = substr($string, length($string)+1, 1);

print Dumper($char);
print Dumper($char2);
```

Besides getting one warning about `substr()` past the end of a string, I'm confused about the output:

```
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR1 = undef;
```

[Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) says about `substr`:

> substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH
>
> If OFFSET and LENGTH specify a substring that is partly outside the string, only the part within the string is returned. If the substring is beyond either end of the string, substr() returns the undefined value and produces a warning.

Both `length($string)` and `length($string) + 1` are beyond the (zero-indexed) end of the string, so I don't know why `substr` returns the empty string in one case and `undef` in the other. Does it have to do with the NULL character that C uses for string termination and that is somehow returned by `substr` in the first case, so that there is an "invisible" last character to this string that is not counted by `length`? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
substr($string, length($string), 1)
```

This gave you an empty string because, `substr` considers the `offset` between `0 to len(str)`, and anything beyond that range is `undef`.

So, `substr("aa", 2, 1);` -> will give you the empty string after last `a`
and,`substr("aa", 3, 1);` -> Will give you `undef` (Substring completely outside range)

**Similarly: -**

- `substr("aa", 2, 2);` -> Will give you the empty string after last
  `a` (Substring partly outside the range)

**Now, for the second one: -**

```
substr($string, length($string) + 1, 1)
```

This is already past the last allowed `offset`. So it returns `undef` value.

Suppose: -

```
$str = "abcd";
```

Then, the index will look like: -

```
  a   b   c   d             undef
0   1   2   3  len(str)  len(str) + 1
```

**UPDATE**: -

So, as @Borodin explained in his post, the character `d` comes between the offsets - `3` and `len(str)` in the above example.

But, if we try to access anything beyond `len(str)` including `len(str)`, we will get an `empty` string, as in the **documentation**, which says that -

> If OFFSET and LENGTH specify a substring that is partly outside the
>   string, only the part within the string is returned.

**Also**, if we try to access anything beyond `len(str)` excluding the `len(str)`, we will get `undef` value, as in **docs**: -

> If the substring is beyond either end of the string, substr() returns
>   the undefined value and produces a warning.

Comment: I actually think this is a perl bug.  While it can be argued that the start of the requested substring is _at_ the end of the string, rather than beyond, the actual contents of the substring is clearly entirely beyond the string, so it should return `undef`.

Comment: @ilmari. Well, if we say that a String ends with an empty string `''`, then I think there is nothing wrong with that. And also, may be this is a bug, because that is assigning an index to that empty string.

Comment: @ilmari. If we see same thing in Java: - **`"ab".endsWith("");`** will return **true**. But, accessing the character at **index 2** by **`"ab".charAt(2)`** throws **an exception**. So may be this is a bug in Perl, or Perl is designed to work that way.

Comment: @Downvoter. Can you please leave a comment, so that I can know what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: I thgink this confuses things unnecessarily. Conceptually there are clearly infinitely many empty strings at every point in a string, but this isn't an explanation. How do you propose to *"[test] whether a string ends with an empty string"*

Comment: @Borodin. Well, I don't know how to do this in Perl. I sure know this works this way in Java, as I have posted in my prevoius comments. So, when I looked into the question, i thought this might be case here too. Doesn't this work this way?

Comment: @Borodin. Also, the result I posted, shows that it is working that way only. I have tested it.

Comment: @RohitJain I can agree that the empty substring at the end of a string is not beyond, e.g. `substr($string, length($string), 0)`. But a non-empty one, e.g. `substr($string, length($string), 1)` _is_ entirely beyond the string.

Comment: @RohitJain: You make it sound as if there is an invisible empty string at the beginning and end of each string, and your ASCII sketch doesn't help - you show an offset equal to the length as *clearly* beyond the end of the string, and try to explain it as if the invisible empty string takes up an extra character position. See my solution

Comment: @ilmari. No it is not entirely beyond, rather `partially beyond`, and if you see the docs statement that OP posted, it says that the substring returns the part of the string in the range if it is partially beyond the range.

Comment: @Borodin. Yeah, your solution makes it clear. thanks for that :) I'll edit my post

Comment: There is little point in changing your solution to a copy of mine

Comment: @Borodin. I have edited the post, in a way I thought it might make sense. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @Borodin. Common. I have not copied it. I understood your post, then I improved mine accordingly, so as to make it sensible. And I don't think there is any harm in this.

Comment: @RohitJain: You have changed your answer completely. Your original explained things in terms of invisible empty strings at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @Borodin. Ok, fine. What do you want me to do? If you didn't wanted the post to be improved, you shouldn't have told me what's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly you should consider the `substr` *offset* to indicate position *between* characters thus:

```
 S T R I N G
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

so you can see that offset 6 - the length of the string - is *at* the end of the string, not beyond it.

Secondly the *length* parameter of `substr` serves as an upper limit to the number of characters returned, not a requirement. That is what the documentation means by *only the part within the string is returned*.

Putting these together, a call like `substr 'STRING', 6, 1` - asking for a *maximum* of one character *at* the end of the string - returns the empty string, while asking for anything *beyond* the end of the string (or before its start) gives `undef`.

Comment: @Borodin.. +1 Ok, I got it now. The indexing makes it more clear. :)

Comment: Thanks to you, too, for additional clarification!